# NullPointerException for KeyAffinityService

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, infinispan

I am trying to implement a distributed system in Infinispan and I wanted to get the key associated with the local node. I was trying to implement this by utilizing the KeyAffinityService but I get a NullPointerException. I was hoping if someone can help me figure my mistake.

## Code snippet

```
    // Create the affinity service to find the Key for the manager  
    KeyAffinityService keyAffinityService = KeyAffinityServiceFactory.newLocalKeyAffinityService(  
            cache,  
            (KeyGenerator)new RndKeyGenerator(),  
            Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),  
            100);
```

The implementation of cache is done as following:

```
    EmbeddedCacheManager manager = new DefaultCacheManager();  
    try{  
        manager = new DefaultCacheManager("democluster.xml");  
    }catch(IOException e){}  
    Cache<Integer, String> cache = manager.getCache();
```

**Xml file**

```
<infinispan  
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:5.1 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-5.1.xsd"  
      xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:5.1">  
    
   <global>  
      <transport clusterName="demoCluster"/>  
      <globalJmxStatistics enabled="true"/>  
   </global>  
  
   <namedCache name="clusteredCache">  
        <clustering mode="distributed">  
        <hash numOwners="1" >  
           <groups enabled="true"/>  
        </hash>  
        </clustering>  
    </namedCache>  
</infinispan>
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException  
  at org.infinispan.affinity.KeyAffinityServiceFactory.newLocalKeyAffinityService(KeyAffinityServiceFactory.java:95)  
  at org.infinispan.affinity.KeyAffinityServiceFactory.newLocalKeyAffinityService(KeyAffinityServiceFactory.java:104)  
  at SimpleCache.start(SimpleCache.java:46)  
  at SimpleCache.main(SimpleCache.java:96)
```

I was wondering if anyone had encountered anything similar or might have any ideas regarding this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong cache, you should be doing

```
Cache<Integer, String> cache = manager.getCache("clusteredCache");
```

KeyAffinityService only works with a distributed cache, and the default cache is local-only (because you don't have a `<default>` element in your configuration).